Monkey pulley problem doubt: why is tension less that weight of body without string break?
*
Why is the weight of the monkey more than the tension without the string breaking? Isn’t this not possible?

You should try and describe the problem with text; not everyone can see images due to browser/SE/other limitations.

If the tension in the string exceeds the weight of the monkey, then the monkey will accelerate upward. The string won't break unless the tension exceeds the string's tensile strength. In most textbook exercises, unless the instructions explicitly say otherwise, you are expected to assume "ideal" values for the material properties of any string or rope or chain. Ideal strength would be infinite, ideal mass would be zero, etc.

The string will break once the tension in the rope exceeds some maximum amount.
If the tension force acting upward on the monkey is less than the weight of the monkey, then that just means the monkey will have a downward acceleration. This does not influence the breaking of the rope.
Perhaps you are getting confused with if the monkey tried to stop its acceleration downward by pulling harder upward on the rope. In that case we could have a situation where the tension force becomes larger, and that could exceed the maximum tension force to cause the rope to break. But the breaking itself does not explicitly depend on the relation between the tension and weight forces.

The limit is specifically the tensile strength of the rope times it’s cross-sectional area (to convert pressure-to-break to force-to-break), or so I’ve been told.

...except, if anybody ever goes out into the real world to buy real cordage, then the "breaking strength" or the "safe working load" that the manufacturer specifies is not per unit area like @controlgroup suggested, it's per whatever-the-whole-cross-section-of-the-cord-actually-is. It's the maximum weight that you could or should dangle from the cord.

Thankss alotttt

@ReetSaini Of course :) Feel free to reach back out if you have any other questions
